# Updating value within resource call's success handler does not reflect in UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I am attempting to update values within my scope upon a successful call to an API endpoint.
Previously I had updated these values as soon as the user clicked 'save'. However, this is less than ideal because even if the API call fails for some reason the UI still reflects the 'new' value until the page is refreshed.

Here is the code in my controller which works, but updates the `id` 'too early':

```
vm.setId = function(user) {
  var _onSuccess = function() {
    alertService.success('Set ' + user.email + ' ID to ' + user.edit.id.value);
  };
  var _onError = function(err) {
    alertService.danger(err.data.message);
  };

  user.id = user.edit.id.value;

  usersService.setId({
    email: user.email,
    id: user.edit.id.value
  }, {}).$promise.then(
    _onSuccess,
    _onError
  );
};
```

This is the code I'm trying to use, but the `id` is not updated to the new value on successful save:

```
vm.setId = function(user) {
  var _onSuccess = function() {
    user.id = user.edit.id.value;
    alertService.success('Set ' + user.email + ' ID to ' + user.edit.id.value);
  };
  var _onError = function(err) {
    alertService.danger(err.data.message);
  };

  usersService.setId({
    email: user.email,
    id: user.edit.id.value
  }, {}).$promise.then(
    _onSuccess,
    _onError
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Caught my issue. I was using one-way data binding in my template, `{{::user.id}}`. Changing this back to two-way binding, `{{user.id}}`, fixed my issue.